# Scipy minimize does not solve the constraint optimization properly (despite showing success )

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have the following simple optimization problem. It is a convex optimization but cvxpy does not recognize it so I use the SciPy minimize to solve it. The problem is as follows:

```
min_{x_1, x_2} (x_1 + x_2 - c)^2

subject to: x_1 / (sig - x_1^2) =  x_2 / (sig - x_2^2)

x_1 , x_2 >= 0
```

The code is

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp
from scipy.linalg import sqrtm
from scipy.optimize import minimize, Bounds, LinearConstraint, NonlinearConstraint
n=2
c = 2.098024636032762
sigma_eigs = np.array([2.56008479, 0.24800215])

def equations(x):
    eq = np.sum(x) - c
    return np.sum(eq**2)


# initial guess for the x values
x0 = np.ones(n) 

# Constraints
bounds = Bounds([0, 0])  # [min x0, min x1]
non_linear_eq= lambda x: x[0] / (sigma_eigs[0] - x[0]**2) - x[1] / (sigma_eigs[1] - x[1]**2)

constr1 = NonlinearConstraint(non_linear_eq, 0, 0)

result = minimize(equations, x0,method='trust-constr' ,constraints=constr1, 
                  bounds= bounds)

x = result.x


print(x)

const_result = [x[i] / (sigma_eigs[i] - x[i]**2) for i in range(n)]

print("The solution is x = {}".format(x))
if np.any(x < 0):
    print("Error: some of the x values are non-positive")
else:
    print("All x values are positive")
    

residuals = equations(x)
print("Residuals are: {}".format(residuals))

if np.any(np.abs(residuals) > 1e-6):
    print("Error: The solution is not accurate. The residuals are high")
else:
    print("All residuals are within the tolerance")


const_result = [x[i] / (sigma_eigs[i] - x[i]**2) for i in range(n)]
```

The result with 'trust-constr is

```
[-2.75911573e-08  1.22830289e+07]
```

The solution is

```
x = [-2.75911573e-08  1.22830289e+07]
```

> Error: some of the x values are non-positive
> Residuals are: 150872747356720.12
> Error: The solution is not accurate. The residuals are high

The optimization message is

> message: xtol termination condition is satisfied.

apparently one of the variables diverges under this method.

Using other methods also gives random results which don't satisfy the constraints. For example running in default solver
`result = minimize(equations, x0 ,constraints=constr1, bounds= bounds)`
gives another incorrect answer:
[0. 0.]
The solution is x = [0. 0.]
All x values are positive
Residuals are: 4.401707373400404
Error: The solution is not accurate. The residuals are high

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your correct result does not satisfy the constraints. `x=[0,0]` technically satisfies your constraints. And why are you checking if your objective is 0? The minimum will not necessarily be 0.

Comment: In addition to what Jared writes: your "correct solution" is particularly malformed since evaluating the Jacobian of the constraint at those values yields massive values > 1e16. Something in your problem construction is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: You've set your "correct solution" to be equal to `sqrt(sigma)`, but that guarantees a divide-by-zero.

Comment: @Reinderien so the answer is correct only in limit. as c approaches cmax = np.sum(np.sqrt(sigma_eigs)) the value of x_i/(sigma_eigs_i - x_i^2) approaches to infinity and the objective function can also approach zero.

Answer (score 1):

I simplified your code (see below) and did not get your "correct" solution. Looking closer, when I try your "correct" solution I see that the constraint is not satisfied, so it is not, in fact, correct. The only point (within 0 and 100) that satisfies the constraint is `x=[0,0]` (I tested this by brute force).

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

n = 2
c = 2.098024636032762
sigma_eigs = np.array([2.56008479, 0.24800215])


def equations(x):
    x1, x2 = x
    eq = x1 + x2 - c
    return eq**2


def non_linear_eq(x):
    return x[0] / (sigma_eigs[0] - x[0]**2) - x[1] / (sigma_eigs[1] - x[1]**2)


result = minimize(equations, np.ones(n),
                  constraints={"type": "eq", "fun": non_linear_eq},
                  bounds=[(0, None), (0, None)])

x = result.x
fun = result.fun


print(f"The solution is {x = }")

if np.all(x >= 0):
    print("All x values are positive.")
else:
    print("Error: Some of the x values are non-positive.")

print(f"The objective function at the solution: {fun}")

constraint_result = non_linear_eq(x)
if np.isclose(constraint_result, 0):
    print("The constraint is satisfied.")
else:
    print(f"Error: The constraint is not satisfied. {constraint_result = }")

x1 = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000)
x2 = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(x1, x2)
x_2d = [x1[:, None], x2[None, :]]
F = equations(x_2d)
const_satisfied = np.where(np.isclose(non_linear_eq(x_2d), 0))
print(f"Points that satisfy the constraint: {np.stack(const_satisfied).T}")
```

Output:

```py
The solution is x = array([0., 0.])
All x values are positive.
The objective function at the solution: 4.401707373400404
The constraint is satisfied.
Points that satisfy the constraint: [[0 0]]
```